# FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined while running karma test

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently testing an application right now using `karma` and `jasmine` and a problem always occurs while `ng test` is running on my cli.

> FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data.
> Unsupported field value: undefined error properties: FirebaseError:
> [code=invalid-argument]: Function Query.where() called with invalid
> data. Unsupported field value: undefined

***`task-settings.component.ts`***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Params, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/services/task.service';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastService } from 'src/app/services/toast.service';
// modal dialog import
@Component({
  selector: 'task-settings',
  templateUrl: './task-settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-settings.component.css'],
})
export class TaskSettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  term!: string;
  dateToday = new Date();
  userData: any;
  fsData: any;
  id!: any;
  taskData: any;
  taskStatus: any = ['Pending', 'Completed'];
  taskScopeArray!: string[];
  newTaskScopeArray!: string[];
  addTaskForm!: any;
  newTaskForm!: any;
  taskRecipients: {
    uid: any;
    status: string;
    section: any;
    submissionLink: string;
    displayName: any;
  }[] = [];
  userPushTokens: { pushToken: string }[] = [];
  addTaskModal!: boolean;
  addScopeModal!: boolean;
  editTaskScope!: any;
  verifyTasks$: any;
  deleteTaskForm!: any;
  deleteTaskModal!: boolean;

  updateTaskForm!: any;
  updateTaskConfirm!: boolean;

  // editTaskScope! : any;
  // end of edit task import

  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    readonly fire: AngularFireAuth,
    private taskService: TaskService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public toastService: ToastService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var d = new Date();
    var y = d.getFullYear();
    var n = d.getMonth();
    console.log(n);
    console.log(y);
    if (n >= 1 && n <= 6) {
      console.log('January to June');
      console.log('2nd Term SY ' + y + '-' + (y + 1));
      this.term = '2nd Term SY ' + y + '-' + (y + 1);
    } else if (n >= 8 && n <= 12) {
      console.log('August to December');
      console.log('1st Term SY ' + y + '-' + (y + 1));
      this.term = '1st Term SY ' + y + '-' + (y + 1);
    } else {
      console.log('Summer Term' + y + '-' + (y + 1));
      this.term = 'Summer Term' + y + '-' + (y + 1);
    }
    this.updateTaskForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      deadline: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.fire.user.subscribe((user: any) => {
      this.userData = user;
      this.auth.getUserData(user?.uid).subscribe((res) => {
        this.fsData = res;
      });
    });
    this.route.params
      .pipe(
        switchMap((params: Params) => {
          console.log(params['id']);
          return this.taskService.getTask(params['id']);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.updateTaskForm.controls.title.setValue(res.title);
        this.updateTaskForm.controls.description.setValue(res.description);
        this.updateTaskForm.controls.deadline.setValue(res.deadline);
        this.taskData = res;
        console.log(res);
      });

    this.taskScopeArray = [];
  }

  public triggerDeleteTaskModal() {
    this.deleteTaskModal = !this.deleteTaskModal;
  }

  public triggerUpdateTask() {
    this.updateTaskForm.controls.title.setValue(this.taskData.title);
    this.updateTaskForm.controls.description.setValue(
      this.taskData.description
    );
    this.updateTaskForm.controls.deadline.setValue(this.taskData.deadline);
  }

  public updateTask() {
    if (this.updateTaskForm.valid) {
      this.taskService.updateTask(
        this.taskData.recipients,
        this.taskData.taskId,
        this.updateTaskForm.controls['title'].value,
        this.updateTaskForm.controls['description'].value,
        new Date (this.updateTaskForm.controls['deadline'].value),
      ).then(() => this.triggerUpdateTask())
      .finally(() => this.updateTaskForm.reset())
    }
    else if (this.updateTaskForm.invalid) {
      this.updateTaskForm.controls['title'].markAsTouched();
      this.updateTaskForm.controls['description'].markAsTouched();
      this.updateTaskForm.controls['deadline'].markAsTouched();


      this.toastService.publish("Please fillup all the requirements","formSuccess");

    }
  }

  changeTaskScope(e: any) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log(typeof e.target.value);
  }

  public deleteTask() {
    this.taskService.deleteTask(this.taskData.taskId).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    });
  }
}
```

***`app.module.ts`***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../app/dashboard-components/dashboard/dashboard.component'
import { LoginComponent } from './auth-components/login/login.component';
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from './pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './auth-components/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { MyProfileComponent } from './my-profile-components/my-profile/my-profile.component';
import { UserManagementComponent } from './user-management-components/user-management/user-management.component';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination'; // <-- import the module
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserComponent } from './user-management-components/user/user.component';
import { TaskComponent } from './dashboard-components/task/task.component';
import { TaskSettingsComponent } from './dashboard-components/task-settings/task-settings.component';
import { ReportComponent } from './dashboard-components/report/report.component';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-chartjs';
import { DownloadReportComponent } from './dashboard-components/download-report/download-report.component';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
import { VerifyTaskComponent } from './user-management-components/verify-task/verify-task.component';

import { UserManualComponent } from './user-manual/user-manual.component';
import { ArchiveComponent } from './archive/archive.component';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    PagenotfoundComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    MyProfileComponent,
    UserManagementComponent,
    UserComponent,
    TaskComponent,
    TaskSettingsComponent,
    ReportComponent,
    DownloadReportComponent,
    VerifyTaskComponent,
    UserManualComponent,
    ArchiveComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ChartModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule, //Firebase imports
    AngularFireFunctionsModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***`task-settings.component.spec.ts`***

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Params, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/services/task.service';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormBuilder, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastService } from 'src/app/services/toast.service';
import { TaskSettingsComponent } from './task-settings.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('TaskSettingsComponent', () => {
  let component: TaskSettingsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TaskSettingsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TaskSettingsComponent ],
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule, AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase), AngularFireDatabaseModule, HttpClientModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule ],
      providers: [ AuthService, TaskService, ToastService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TaskSettingsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Where are you calling `.where()` ?  Please share your `.spec.ts` file.

Comment: is it in the `spec.ts` file?